# How can I check foreign key on delete restrict

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a problem with my website, when I want to delete an item that is already ordered by someone I can't deleted (that is normal since I have a restrict ON delete and ON update in my database). But my question is instead of getting nothing on the screen I want to get a text saying something. This is my code.

```
if (isset($_GET['verwijder'])) {

    $id = $_GET['verwijder'];
    $db_conn->query("DELETE FROM `menu` WHERE menu_id=$id");
    header("location:../menu.php");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then test the result of the query, delete queries return true or false

```
$res = $db_conn->query("DELETE FROM `menu` WHERE menu_id=$id");
if ( ! $res ) {
    echo 'something';
}
```

> WARNING: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values